# Carousel-caption stays below overlay even with higher z-index

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want my Bootstrap carousel to have a dotted overlay above the images. The Carousel Caption should be above the dotted overlay.
I can't get it to work with z-indexes.

Am I doing something wrong? (quiet possibly :-))

Here is a JS Fiddle of what i have so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/r4x99ecf/50/

HTML:

```
<div class="banner">
<div class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8hAR6s4.jpg" />
            <div class="carousel-caption">This is a caption of image 1.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/BPSXgEp.jpg" />
            <div class="carousel-caption">This is a caption of image 2.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel, .carousel-inner {
height: 350px;
}

.overlay {
background: transparent url("http://i.imgur.com/8B7UFiv.png") repeat;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}
.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15%;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 15%;
  z-index: 10;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  font-size:22px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like Srinivas said, or you can do it like this

http://jsfiddle.net/766omu70/1/

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8hAR6s4.jpg" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">This is a caption of image 1.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/BPSXgEp.jpg" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">This is a caption of image 2.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Vk1Y6v0.jpg" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">This is a caption of image 3.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel, .carousel-inner {
    height: 350px;
}

.item:before{
    content:"";
    background: transparent url("http://i.imgur.com/8B7UFiv.png") repeat;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15%;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 15%;
  z-index: 10;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  font-size:22px;
}
```

I put the overlay as a pseudoelement, no additional divs necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Add `<div class="overlay"></div>` in each section of the `.item`

**HTML**

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8hAR6s4.jpg" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">This is a caption of image 1.</div>
                <div class="overlay"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/BPSXgEp.jpg" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">This is a caption of image 2.</div>
                 <div class="overlay"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Vk1Y6v0.jpg" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">This is a caption of image 3.</div>
                 <div class="overlay"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/r4x99ecf/51/